# Bearing and Speed are not available when minTime and minDistance are set in Android Things

Tags: android, gps, android-things, bearing

I have an issue when I set the parameters minTime and minDistance, the locations are returned without speed and bearing information, I am using AndroidThings in a Raspberry PI. I have another version running in Android Phone version 7.0 and it is working as expected.

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,300, 3, mLocationListener);
```

if I change the values to 0 then it works fine:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, mLocationListener);
```

Comment: ...and does it work if you move 3 meters?

Comment: I did the tests outside, going around 500m,

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty interesting, and I could speculate about the reasons your phone supports this, while your Pi doesn't, but it turns out it the issue is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html):

> All locations generated by the LocationManager are guaranteed to have a valid latitude, longitude, and timestamp... all other parameters are optional.

The good news is, work-arounds are readily available, and they give *you* control over the speed/bearing semantics (which otherwise might have been left up to the OEM implementation of the `LocationManager` logic).

**WORKAROUND 1**

- Retain the last fix
- For each new fix that comes in, compare it to the last one using `lastFix.bearingTo(newFix)` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo(android.location.Location))). The speed can likewise be calculated from A.) `distanceTo()`, and B.) the elapsed time, which is `newFix.getTime() - lastFix.getTime()`.

With this workaround, each bearing is defined as the bearing from the last fix to the current fix, and it is available as soon as the new fix comes in.

**WORKAROUND 2**

- Set `minTime` and `minDistance` to 0
- Retain the "first" fix
- Update the speed/bearing as each new fix comes in (display on the UI, or whatever).
- Use your own logic to determine when a fix has exceeded 3m/300ms from the "first" fix (using the methods mentioned above), and ignore all lat/longs until that time. Then, of course, you replace the "first" fix with the current fix, and repeat.

With this workaround, the bearing and speed at any given moment do not correspond to the next "official" fix (but they could, if properly integrated over each individual "mini-fix").

I do not know if this higher update rate has any power-management implications for your Pi, but I doubt it. In other words, it shouldn't cost you anything, in terms of battery efficiency.